# Get id field as an int of a record in QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql, qsqltablemodel, qcompleter

I am using `QSqlTableModel *modelcompleter`, and then using  `QCompleter` to load the data into the `qLineEdit *search`

```
    connect(ui->btnSearch, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(search()));
    modelcompleter->setTable("cust");
    modelcompleter->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    modelcompleter->select();
    QCompleter *searchCompleter = new QCompleter(modelcompleter);
    searchCompleter->setCompletionColumn(1);
    searchCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    ui->search->setCompleter(searchCompleter);
```

I am using qlineEdit to hit enter on the item that I want to choose:

```
 connect(ui->search, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), SLOT(search()));
```

the function

```
void search(){
cust_name = ui->search->text();
    modelsearch->setTable("cust");
    modelsearch->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    modelsearch->setFilter(QString("cust_name like '%%1%'").arg(cust_name));
    modelsearch->select();
    qDebug() << modelsearch->record(0).value("id").toInt(); }
```

I don't understand why but the modelsearch which currently sets to only 1 record that it gets when I hit enter (QCompleter makes sure I submit the full 'cust_name'). QDebug() outputs 0. Is there another way to get the `id` of the `'cust_name'` that matches the search query `'cust_name'`

Answer (score 1):

```
qDebug() << modelsearch->record(0).value("id").toInt();
```

instead of this. I used

```
QSqlQueryModel *query = new QSqlQueryModel;
query->setQuery(QString("SELECT id from cust WHERE cust_name like '%%1%'").arg(cust_name));
qDebug() << query->record(0).value("id").toInt();
```

and its now fetching the id of the record!